Is this le (indirect object pronoun) redundant?

La parte arrendataria le comunica a la parte arrendadora que perdería la fianza.

In the sentence the owner (la parte arrendataria) is telling the tenant (la parte arrendadora) that the tenant will loose the deposit.
"Le" seems to refer to the la parte arrendadora.
Can the "le" be omitted?

Not at all. comunicarse. You don't say what is being communicated so the sentence is not grammatical. Also, why use the conditional if you don't say why?

I just checked 3 different dictionaries, and "arrendataria" is tenant, and "arrendadora" is owner.

@PeterM Good point. Event as native speaker I need to check the meaning of those words. Shitty legal language, hard to understand in any country. owner/tenant or dueño/inquilino is pretty much clear.

@RubioRic Is there any country/language in the world where the legal system is written in plain words? /s

arrendataria and arrendadora can also be: lessee and lessor, fyi. I do legal translation.

@RubioRic Why aren't you commenting on the fact the sentence is incorrect? Le comunica qué? The tenant (lessee) communicates with owner (lessor) com who loses the deposit? Really? Maybe: it's lo, that would change it, right?

@Lambie I edited my answer multiple times for including my opinion regarding what  Peter and you have mentioned

@Lambie "Le comunica que perdería la fianza" es correcto. Desde mi punto de vista, faltan las condiciones en que se perdería dicha fianza. "Le comunica que perdería la fianza en caso de: tener mascotas, causar desperfectos en el mobiliario, no pagar mensualidad antes del día 5, ... "

La parte arrendataria lo [que no sabemos]  comunica a la parte arrendadora que perdería la fianza. Now yes. Si claro lo que dices es cierto.

Duplicating the indirect object or the direct object is pretty common in Spanish, as you can see here.
In relation with your sentence you can also find this detailed explanation:

Se ha observado, no obstante, que la ausencia de doblado en estas
construcciones es más propia de la lengua escrita que de la oral. En
el registro conversacional de muchos países hispanohablantes se siente
poco natural la ausencia de doblado en secuencias como Di la noticia a
mi marido (o a mi esposo, según los países) en lugar de Le di la
noticia a mi marido, ya que la primera variante se asocia con un nivel
de lengua más formal.

That more or less can be translated as

It has been observed that the absence of the duplicate in these constructions is more characteristic in writing that in speaking. [...] in a lot of Spanish-speaking countries they feel less natural the absence of the duplicate in sequences like Di la noticia a mi marido instead of Le di la noticia a mi marido because the first variant is associated with a more formal level of speaking

So applying that to your sentence, the answer is yes, it can be omitted, but such variant is considered more formal. Talking about contracts and official communications such level is usual.

La parte arrendataria comunica a la parte arrendadora que perdería la fianza.

In any case, as noted by Lambie, the sentence seems uncompleted. It's missing the condition that describes in which cases the deposit will be lost.
On the other hand, as PeterM commented, "parte arrendataria" means tenant and "parte arrendadora" means owner. Usually it's the owner the one that communicates cases in which the deposit will not be returned. So it should be

La parte arrendadora comunica a la parte arrendataria que perdería la fianza en los siguientes supuestos: ... [listado de condiciones]

Some conditions that can result in losing the deposit (in Spanish):

Tener mascotas
Causar desperfectos en el mobiliario
No pagar la mensualidad antes del día 5 del mes


[incomplete] :)

While I am not a native speaker, in my opinion the "le" cannot be omitted.
Within this sentence, the "La parte arrendataria" is announcing/stating (comunicar) that " .. perdería la fianza.".  So that person is performing the action.
However, the action is not being performed in a vacuum.  Instead it is being directed at  "la parte arrendadora", who are the recipient of the action (announcing/stating).  As such, you need a "le" to indicate the recipient of the action.  And because the "la parte arrendadora" hasn't been defined before this sentence in some manner, you still need to specify who was actually receiving the action.
(If the previous sentence had mentioned something about the two parties meeting, then you could drop the full explanation of who both parties are from your example sentence sentence.)
This form is exactly the same as for other verbs like "dar" for example.  So you could say:

La parte arrendataria le da una carta a la parte arrendadora

The action is the owner giving a letter, but the recipient is the tenant.

The sentence does not work at all since we have no idea what is being communicated UNLESS le should really be lo.
